PyTorch > TorchScript tensor.view() alternative?
I have the following code:
@torch.jit.script
def my_function(t: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    if t.dtype != torch.bfloat16:
        raise ValueError("Input tensor must be of dtype torch.bfloat16")
    int_type = torch.int16
    t_bits = t.view(int_type) <- error

That throws:
RuntimeError: shape '[2]' is invalid for input of size 1

Because, given the documentation:
.. warning::
This overload is not supported by TorchScript, and using it in a 
Torchscript program will cause undefined behavior.

So the question is, what's the alternative for use?

You can use .to instead of .view.
@torch.jit.script
def my_function(t: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    if t.dtype != torch.bfloat16:
        raise ValueError("Input tensor must be of dtype torch.bfloat16")
    int_type = torch.int16
    t_bits = t.to(int_type)
    return t_bits

The "overload" in question is that typically .view is used for changing the shape of a tensor, but pytorch "overloads" the .view operation to also allow for changing the tensor dtype. You can use .to instead.
